# Raphael JS to draw concentric lines

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm stuck using Raphael JS : **I want to make a basic animation that draws concentric lines while loading some stuff**.

So, I made this function :

```
function loadingButton(width, height) {

    width = width ? width : 240;
    height = height ? height : 240;




    var loadingButton = Raphael("loading-button", width, height);
    var center = 120,
        xloc = center,
        yloc = center,
        R = 120,
        imgW = 124,
        imgH = 140;
    var lines;
    var percent = loadingButton.text(center, center, '0');
    percent.attr({'font-size': 36, 'fill': '#fff'});
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){

        if( count <= 100){
            var start_x = center+Math.round((center-30)*Math.cos(4*count*Math.PI/200));
            var start_y = center+Math.round((center-30)*Math.sin(4*count*Math.PI/200));
            var end_x = center+Math.round((center-10)*Math.cos(4*count*Math.PI/200));
            var end_y = center+Math.round((center-10)*Math.sin(4*count*Math.PI/200));   
            lines = loadingButton.path("M"+start_x+" "+start_y+"L"+end_x+" "+end_y).attr({"stroke":"#FFF","stroke-width":"1"});
            percent.attr({text: count});
            count++;
        }

        else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 50);






};
```

**With live demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/rfuqjL65/**

*The thing is, as you can see on the fiddle, the animation is starting on the first quarter (90°), not on the top (0°).*

And well, the problem is : **I want the animation starts on the top**.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your fiddle running, but:

You can add/substract `Math.PI/2` to the angle argument (in radians) for `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` in your coordinate variables, that should do the trick!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the fiddle's console ? Can you provide an answer containing the modified parts of the code ? (I don't see where to add/substract Math.PI/2 :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rfuqjL65/1/ does this work for you? also, I've clarified my answer

Comment: Well, the exemple doesn't work : it says Raphael is not defined, when Raphael should be loaded by JSFiddle... But your answer works nice thanks !

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rfuqjL65/2/
I change your code. And this worked.
And also

```
 var start_x = center+Math.round((center-30)*Math.sin(4*count*Math.PI/200));
                var start_y = center-Math.round((center-30)*Math.cos(4*count*Math.PI/200));
                var end_x = center+Math.round((center-10)*Math.sin(4*count*Math.PI/200));
                var end_y = center-Math.round((center-10)*Math.cos(4*count*Math.PI/200));
```